# How can I tell in a custom handler if a submission is new?

Tags: 8, webforms

I need to do some actions after a new submission for a webform is created. So I have created a new handler, and I'm using the function:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission)
```

But this functions triggers whenever I edit the webform too. Is there a way to know if it's a new submission?

Comment: Isn't it when you add the handler through the UI, that you simply can check "is completed" and leave "update" unchecked?

Comment: With proper autocompletion you can see, that there's `$webform_submission->isNew()` and `$webform_submission->isCompleted()`.

Comment: I can't find those checkboxes when adding the handler. I'll try the functions $webform_submission->isNew(). Thanks.